# Getting column name where a condition matches in a row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `pandas` dataframe which looks like this:

```
        A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I
1       0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2       1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
3       0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Now, for each `row`, I have to check which `column` contains `1` and then record this column name in a new column. The final `dataframe` would look like this:

```
        A     B     C     D     E     F     G     H     I     IsTrue
1       0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   B
2       1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   A
3       0.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   B
```

Is there any faster and `pythonic` way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using [`DataFrame.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
df['isTrue'] = df.astype(bool).dot(df.columns)

    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    isTrue
1  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      B
2  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      A
3  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0      B
```

---

For an even better performance you can use:

```
df['isTrue'] = df.columns[df.to_numpy().argmax(1)]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I am going with this one as it is much faster

Answer (score 0):

What you described is the definition of [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html)

```
>>> df.idxmax(1)
```

```
1    B
2    A
3    B
dtype: object
```

Comment: But this is slower than the others

Comment: To be precise, on my data and on my machine, this is `3x` slower than the first answer and `2x` slower than the second one

Comment: @mlRocks that's indeed true for binary (0 & 1) values data frame cause the dot product is very fast ;} the gain of `idxmax` is that it is generic for non-binary data